# Extract a single file from a ZIP archive

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip, system.io.compression

I'm using the next code to download some zip archive:

```sh
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LatestChromeRelease/chromedriver_win32.zip","D:\MyFolder.zip")
```

As the result I get the ZIP archive "MyFolder.zip" that contains a required file (lets imagine 'test.txt').

How I can extract this particular file from the ZIP archive into a given folder?

Comment: If you're on PowerShell 4 and up, you will have the `Expand-Archive` command available.  Use that to unzip the archive to wherever you want.  Then you use the `Copy-item` command to take the file from that unzipped folder and do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 11):

PowerShell 4+ has an [`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) command but as of PS 7.2.3 it can only extract the archive completely. So extract it to a temporary directory and copy the file you are interested in.

If you have PS 5.1+ available, scroll down for a more efficient solution that uses .NET classes.

```sh
$archivePath = 'D:\MyFolder.zip'
$destinationDir = 'D:\MyFolder'

# Relative path of file in ZIP to extract. 
$fileToExtract = 'test.txt'

# Create destination dir if not exist.
$null = New-Item $destinationDir -ItemType Directory -Force

# Create a unique temporary directory
$tempDir = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString('n'))
$null = New-Item $tempDir -ItemType Directory

try {
    # Extract archive to temp dir
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $archivePath -DestinationPath $tempDir

    # Copy the file we are interested in
    $tempFilePath = Join-Path $tempDir $fileToExtract
    Copy-Item $tempFilePath $destinationDir 
}
finally {
    # Remove the temp dir
    if( Test-Path $tempDir ) { 
        Remove-Item $tempDir -Recurse -Force -EA Continue 
    }
}
```

With **PS 5.1+** you can use [.NET classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0) to directly extract a single file (without having to extract the whole archive):

```sh
# Load required .NET assemblies. Not necessary on PS Core 7+.
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$archivePath = 'D:\MyFolder.zip'
$destinationDir = 'D:\MyFolder'

# Relative path of file in ZIP to extract.
# Use FORWARD slashes as directory separator, e. g. 'subdir/test.txt'
$fileToExtract = 'test.txt'

# Create destination dir if not exist.
$null = New-Item $destinationDir -ItemType Directory -Force

# Convert (possibly relative) paths for safe use with .NET APIs
$resolvedArchivePath    = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $archivePath
$resolvedDestinationDir = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $destinationDir

$archive = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead( $resolvedArchivePath )
try {
    # Locate the desired file in the ZIP archive.
    # Replace $_.Fullname by $_.Name if file shall be found in any sub directory.
    if( $foundFile = $archive.Entries.Where({ $_.FullName -eq $fileToExtract }, 'First') ) {
    
        # Combine destination dir path and name of file in ZIP
        $destinationFile = Join-Path $resolvedDestinationDir $foundFile.Name
        
        # Extract the file.
        [IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile( $foundFile[ 0 ], $destinationFile )
    }
    else {
        Write-Error "File not found in ZIP: $fileToExtract"
    }
}
finally {
    # Dispose the archive so the file will be unlocked again.
    if( $archive ) {
        $archive.Dispose()
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- `Convert-Path` should be used when passing PowerShell paths that might be relative paths, to .NET APIs. The .NET framework has its own current directory, which doesn't necessarily match PowerShell's. Using `Convert-Path` we convert to absolute paths so the current directory of .NET is no longer relevant.
- `.Where` and `.ForEach` are PowerShell [intrinsic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#methods) that are available on all objects. They are similar to the `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object` commands but more efficient. Passing `'First'` as the 2nd argument to `.Where` stops searching as soon as we have found the file.
- Note that `.Where` always outputs a *collection*, even if only a single element matches. This is contrary to `Where-Object` which returns a *single object* if only a single element matches. So we have to write `$foundFile[ 0 ]` when passing it to function `ExtractToFile`, instead of just `$foundFile` which would be an array.

Comment: Using the PS 5.1 version, I got error "Method invocation failed because [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive] does not contain a method named 'Close'."  But when the "$archive.Close()" line is removed, it works great.

Answer (score 2):

If you can and want to install modules, this process can be simplified using the [PSCompression Module](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression) (**disclaimer:** *I'm the maintainer of this Module*).

Extracting one or more entries from a Zip Archive would look like this:

```bash
Get-ZipEntry D:\MyFolder.zip -Include */test.txt |
    Expand-ZipEntry -Destination path\to\myDestinationFolder
```

<sub>Note: If the `test.txt` was on the Zip's root then you would simply use `-Include test.txt`. See also [`-Include`](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/en-US/Get-ZipEntry.md#-include) for more details.</sub>

For more examples on these two cmdlets, you can check the docs: [Expand-ZipEntry.md#examples](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/en-US/Expand-ZipEntry.md#examples) and [Get-ZipEntry.md#examples](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/en-US/Get-ZipEntry.md#examples).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just use `tar` which is available in Windows 10 and later.